# How to know all the available BASE_FORM_ID?

Tags: forms

I know just a few BASE_FORM_ID to use with the `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` hook, there is an old article named [Using hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](https://www.bryanbraun.com/2013/08/17/using-hook-form-base-form-id-alter/) talking about this.

In the article there is a method to know if a form have en BASE_FORM_ID

> [image]

But, how to know all the available BASE_FORM_ID in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In D8 only entity forms implement the interface `BaseFormIdInterface`. The code to generate the base form id is in `EntityForm::getBaseFormId`:

```
  public function getBaseFormId() {
    // Assign ENTITYTYPE_form as base form ID to invoke corresponding
    // hook_form_alter(), #validate, #submit, and #theme callbacks, but only if
    // it is different from the actual form ID, since callbacks would be invoked
    // twice otherwise.
    $base_form_id = $this->entity->getEntityTypeId() . '_form';
    if ($base_form_id == $this->getFormId()) {
      $base_form_id = NULL;
    }
    return $base_form_id;
  }
```

So for each config and content entity type there is a base form id available: `[ENTITY_TYPE]_form`

In some cases special entity forms override this method, for example the confirm form class `ContentEntityConfirmFormBase` defines `[ENTITY_TYPE]_confirm_form`.

To get all available base form ids the best approach is probably to iterate over all routes that have entity forms or build the form object with the information you find in the entity types. The most work here is to get an entity for the form object, because `getBaseFormID()` depends on this:

```
use Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityType;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityType;

$entityTypeManager = \Drupal::EntityTypeManager();
$base_form_ids = [];
foreach ($entityTypeManager->getDefinitions() as $id => $entity_type) {
  $handler_classes = $entity_type->getHandlerClasses();
  // check if the entity type has form operations
  if (isset($handler_classes['form'])) {
    $entity = NULL;
    // for config load the first entity
    if ($entity_type instanceof ConfigEntityType) {
      $entity = reset($entityTypeManager->getStorage($id)->loadMultiple());
    }
    // for content create a new instance, because we don't know if content exists
    elseif ($entity_type instanceof ContentEntityType) {
      $values = [];
      // if the entity type has bundles we have to provide one when we create the entity
      if ($bundle_key = $entity_type->getKey('bundle')) {
        if ($bundle_entity_type_id = $entity_type->getBundleEntityType()) {
          if ($bundle = reset($entityTypeManager->getStorage($bundle_entity_type_id)->loadMultiple())) {
            $values[$bundle_key] = $bundle->id();
          }
        }
      }
      $entity = $entityTypeManager->getStorage($id)->create($values);
    }
    // if we have an entity, get the base form id for each form operation
    if ($entity) {
      foreach ($handler_classes['form'] as $operation => $form_class) {  
        $form_object = $entityTypeManager->getFormObject($id, $operation);
        $form_object->setEntity($entity);
        if ($base_form_id = $form_object->getBaseFormId()) {
          $base_form_ids[$base_form_id] = $base_form_id;  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I need to create a code to get first all the entities in the site and then call this method? This sounds good to you?

Comment: Only entity forms have the concept of a base ID in Drupal 8 @AdrianCidAlmaguer, it isn't really the same as it was in 7. If you want to get a list of all the entity base forms, then yes what you outlined should work fine

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, yes, this would be one approach, or look for routes which have entity form classes

Comment: @Clive if there is not a simply way to do this I'll try to create a drush command for this.

Comment: you could use drupal console `drupal entity:debug` to get all entities and then append `_form`

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Thinking about it a bit more, that might not be worth it; pretty much everything is an entity in D8 anyway so that's what you're going to be dealing with 99% of the time

Comment: @4k4 That'd probably make a good addition to the answer

Comment: @Clive & Adrian Cid Almaguer, the approach to look in the route definitions is a better idea, see the edit

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer, found a solution based on the entity type definitions, see edit

Comment: I get an empty array

Comment: I get 65 base form id's. Did your IDE find the correct use statements? I add them to the code.

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 7 you can invoke [`hook_forms`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_forms/7.x) and you'll find the info in the 'callback' returned value.

> Return value
>
> An associative array whose keys define form_ids and whose values are
>   an associative array defining the following keys:
>
> **callback**: The callable returning the form array. If it is the name of
>   the form builder function then this will be used for the base form ID,
>   for example, to target a base form using
>   hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter(). Otherwise use the base_form_id key to
>   define the base form ID.

Use this code to get the values:

```
$base_forms = [];
foreach (module_invoke_all('forms') as $form) {
  if (!in_array($form['callback'], $base_forms)) {
    $base_forms[] = $form['callback'];
  }
}
// To use dpm() you need the devel module.
dpm($base_forms);
```

Comment: you code for drupal 7 works great! I just will edit your answer with aditional info.

Comment: This doesn't work if the hook implementation requires arguments, such as webform or entityform. It should be `foreach (module_invoke_all('forms', '', []) as $form) {`